# How to aggregate histograms for density estimation

Tags: inference, kernel-smoothing, histogram, aggregation, density-estimation

Within a very large sensor network, each node does take measurements derived from a fixed number of samples taken at a high frequency from an instrument. The number of measurements send to an aggregation server varies and is triggered by the environment, but the number of samples taken from the instrument is always the same. There is a latency associated with each acquired sample which follows a possibly multi-modal distribution, the distribution of this latency over the whole population is what is in question. On each network node, the latency can be measured and its per-node-distribution is estimated via an histogram. Min, max, and bin size are fixed and the same on each node. Each node can transmit this histogram as part of the upstream payload.

Now the question is, can one derive an estimate for the latency density function for the whole population (‘population histogram’) by some sort of aggregation over the histograms shipped by each node?

I first was thinking one could sum over the counts in each histogram, but some nodes supply way more counts per bin than others, meaning that the nodes with fewer counts will be dominated by the one with less, such that the population histogram will not reflect the population but only a few chatty nodes.

Next, I thought normalizing the histograms before bin aggregation (generating a PMF estimate) would be a solution, but I am afraid that sparsely populated histograms from some clients would concentrate the mass in a small area, which in turn would perturb a population aggregate.

I was not able to find much information on the topic of estimating population density from an ensemble of histograms. I don’t really know what field/sub topic of statistic this might fall under, so if there is something I might not be aware of, I would be grateful for any pointers in the right direction to tackle this problem. Thanks.